# Google List API PDF Upload with Java

Tags: java, pdf, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am looking to upload a PDF using the resumable upload mechanism.  However, the web server is throwing a 403 exception which states: "Files must uploaded using the resumable upload mechanism."
This is particularly frustrating, since, the resumable upload mechanism is what I'm using.  I am able to change the file to a .txt and it works efficiently.

```
String contentType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file3.getName()).getMimeType();
System.out.println("This is break zero.");
MediaFileSource mediaFile = new MediaFileSource(file3, contentType);
System.out.println("This is break one.");
ResumableGDataFileUploader uploader =
      new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(
          client, new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"), mediaFile, null /*empty meatadata*/)
          .title(mediaFile.getName())
          .chunkSize(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE).executor(executor)
          .trackProgress(listener, PROGRESS_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
          .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the request to the resumable upload url, which is `https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full`.

Check the resumable upload documentation for more details: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/resumable_upload